# Importing a *.txt file to excel from a variable text name (VBA)

Tags: excel, variables, import, vba

Went through some threads to get some advise on importing a *.txt file to Excel but can't get the revised code to work:
(Before this part of code application asks the user for the file path which `lollot` variable clears of the file path).

```
Dim lollot As String

lollot = Replace(strFileToOpen, file path, "")

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & lollot, Destination:= _
    Range("A1"))
    .Name = lollot
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .CommandType = 0
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 _
    , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 _
    )
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

So the code doesn't give any error messages when it's run, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: This line `lollot = Replace(strFileToOpen, file path, "")` won't even compile because of syntax error!

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I modified it to not show the actual folder i was working with...

Comment: There is a `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` missing before `End With`

Comment: Dropped it out because Excel was giving an error for it, could the solution be to add it back?

Comment: Ask yourself "*Can it be a solution to just delete any line that throws an error?*" … "No, never!" That's not how we fix errors. Without `.Refresh` no refresh, therefore no data loaded! If there is an error then read that error understand it and fix it. I'm sure the error didn't say delete that line. So I suggest you [edit] your original question, show your original code, tell us which error you get and where.

Comment: Haha, sorry xD, you're absolutely right. Edited the code a little bit. I also had .Commandtype = 0 and it gives an "Invalid procedure call or argument" in excel.

Comment: yes I get that too, but that seems actually to be an Excel bug. So if you remove `.CommandType = 0` it should work if your filename is correct. Actually that is a bug from the macro recorder that puts the `.CommandType = 0` where it should not.

Comment: Okay now it's working, thanks a lot!! And sorry once again! :)